# SE site to ask about career advice

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In the Academia SE, I can talk about academic professionalism, expectations, and advice. I'd like to know what SE site discusses similar topics related to careers/jobs. I have some questions I'd like to ask or research regarding answering certain questions in interviews, wording something on my resume, and getting endorsements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have some questions I'd like to ask or research regarding answering certain questions in interviews, wording something on my resume, and getting endorsements.

That would most certainly be [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), which is basically the office version of Academia.

Be sure to [take their tour first](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! I'd accept your answer, but I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: I thought you could always accept an answer, regardless of reputation. (However you can't upvote without having 15 rep)

Comment: @user355381 [How do I accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Ah, I was doing this on mobile and the error message went away too quickly, I believe I wasn't able to accept the answer within a certain time frame, but it works now, thanks!